# How do I get current action parameter?

Tags: php, caching, parameters, yii2, action

I'm using a `yii\filters\PageCache` filter for my action and I want to define a cache dependency based on action parameter.

E.g. I want to use `yii\caching\DbDependency` to select `updated_at` column of the row with `id` from the request. How can I reference the `id` parameter of the action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Yii::$app->request->get('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add dependency in your cache then try this

```
 $db = Yii::$app->db; // or Category::getDb()
        $dep = new DbDependency();
        $dep->sql = 'SELECT max(update_at) FROM table';
        $model = $db->cache(function ($db) {
            return model::find()->asArray()->orderBy('id ASC')->all();

        },expirytime, $dep);
```

The code will check your data in cache if it exist will load from cache otherwise create it and cached it.it will also check your update_at filed if its value is changed then it will update your cache,you don't need to worry about that
and if you want to access current action in yii then try this code

```
 Yii::$app->controller->id; //will return current controller//
    Yii::$app->controller->action->id; //will return current action//
Yii::$app->controller->module->id; //will return current module//
```

i hope this will help you